# How can I show 3 images continuously for each 2 sec in the main screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimage

I have one **viewcontroller**. In that i placed imageview fully. And i have 3 images like `img1,img2,img3`. So every time that 3 image should continuously show for every 2 second with out swipe.

How to do that in code. And also at bottom of my viewcontroller i have two action button.so only that background image should move continuously for every 2 second per image. My button should be at same place.

i am new to start ios, please help me how to do that. Without user swipe i need to show that 3 image continuously for each 2 second. please help me thanks!.Your solution will help full for me.

Comment: Use timer, to load the image into imageview.

Comment: Or, ya know, `UIImageView`'s built in image animation functionality via the `animationImages` and `animationDuration` properties...

Comment: Thanks for your response. I started ios with 15 days only. Please give some code explain.That will be help full....I can learn for my further imporvement

Comment: i am not gud at animating uiimage....please help me sir.with some code explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can use `UIImageView`'s built in animation functionality for this.

The interface for this is *really* simple.

- You pass an `NSArray` of images to cycle through to the `animationImages` property of the `UIImageView`.
- You pass an `NSTimeInterval` to the `animationDuration` property that specifies how long an *entire* cycle takes.
- You can then call `startAnimating` and `stopAnimating` to start and stop your animation.

**For example, something like this should achieve your desired effect:**

```
@implementation ViewController {
    UIImageView* imgView; // your UIImageView
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // define your images
    UIImage* img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.PNG"];
    UIImage* img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.PNG"];
    UIImage* img3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.PNG"];

    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]; // create a UIImageView with the same size as the view.
    imgView.animationImages = @[img1, img2, img3]; // use a nice NSArray literal to pass in your images.
    imgView.animationDuration = 2.0*3.0; // 2 seconds for each image (x3 images)
    [self.view addSubview:imgView]; // add UIImageView to view

    [imgView startAnimating]; // start animating
}

@end
```

**For more information, take a look at the `UIImageView` [docs on animating images.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006889-CH3-SW8)**

Comment: actually, after re-reading your question (it isn't *amazingly* clear), I think you actually want a 'swipe' out animation for the images... for that you'll want to create a custom animation view. This answer should give you a good idea on how to do basic image cycling with a `UIImageView` though. I can work on a more custom solution if I have the time, but not right now.

Comment: i dont need swipe. Foe very 2 second that all images should continuously shown

Comment: @martin that's alright then! This code does exactly that.